# How to parse xml using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, decision-tree

I have xml which have different nodes.
I want to build decision tree logic using xml.

Is there any js library to parse xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not one to throw jQuery out there, but in this case it does a good job. [Check out jQuery's `parseXML()` function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). It returns an easy to use jQuery object to play with.

Comment: Thank you. It works as per my requirement.